# Error while using cucumber with rails for automated testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm starting in the automated testing area and am having the error below when I am running one of my tests. The test would be to fill in a datetime field, of type input, with the start time that the machine stopped. I'm running Cucumber with Capybara on a system written in Ruby on Rails and Ext Js.

```
Error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Bellow is my env.rb for the project:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'report_builder'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_driver = :selenium_chrome 
    config.default_max_wait_time=10
    config.app_host='http://localhost:3000/'
end
```

My exemple.feature is like:

```
Scenario: start of the machine stop
Given that I accessed the system
And marked 'Yes' in 'Did the machine stop?'
And I fill the start of the machine stop with '2020-05-12 16:00:00' #UTC
When saving the form
Then the success message should appear
```

My steps.rb is something like below:

```
And("I fill the start of the machine stop with {string}") do
  @machine_stop = machine_stop
  @MD.machine_stop_start(@machine_stop)
end
```

My page.rb:

```
class Machine_downtime
    include Capybara::DSL

    def machine_stop_start
        find('input[id="datetimefield-1312-inputEl"]').click
    end
end
```

I've done a Google search to find possible solutions but I haven't found any similar cases. I tried to look at the Cucumber documentation but I didn't find anything specific to my problem or Rails.
I can stop using a strings in the step and use a table, but I have more scenarios in this case and I would like to continue using strings, for easier maintenance and to avoid having to change more than 100 test scenarios.

I appreciate anyone who can help me with the problem.

P.s. Ruby on Rails runs on a different project.

Comment: The problem is that you defined a method `machine_stop_start` that doesn't receive any parameters, and you're sending one `@MD.machine_stop_start(@machine_stop)`, that will generate the error.

Comment: Now in the morning I had that same thought but I haven't found anything yet on how to put the machine_stop_start method waiting for an argument. Yesterday I looked for documentation and in Cucumber forums, today I'm searching for Capybara, see if I can find any light.
Thanks for comment c:

Comment: Update#2

I adjusted the method and step and I'm filling the field with the information passed in the String.

Comment: its far easier to use cucumber-rails to test rails projects and have the features in the rails project. Why aren't you doing this?

Comment: @diabolist We are still starting the automation project and it was decided for now to keep the two projects separate.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I insert in the machine_stop_start method the variable I created in the step and the error no longer occurs.

```
class Machine_downtime
    include Capybara::DSL

    def machine_stop_start (machine_stop)
        find('input[id="datetimefield-1312-inputEl"]').click
    end
end
```

Now I am able to click on the desired field but it is not being filled with the desired information. 
I will try to find what I may be doing wrong.